# button cannot be disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one button in a

```
<form action="/" method="POST" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
      .....  
       <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I am trying to disable it in JQuery

```
$('#contactForm button.submit').prop('disabled', true)
```

This thing does not work. It does not work either when I inspect the button on chrome and set it as `disabled` manually.

Is there another way to make the button `disabled`?

Comment: I just created a fiddle with your code exactly and the button is definitely disabled. https://jsfiddle.net/zjmwf17d/6/

Comment: You problem is somewhere else, as @Gavin said

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#contactForm button.submit').attr('disabled', true);
```